# Azure website - 404 - yet, published fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, web, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I’ve looked into this (on and off now) for over a month… and frankly, I’m at a loss.  I would appreciate anyone pointing me to some answers here.  I've searched the web for answers – and thus far have found none.

Here is my situation:

- We have a working MVC 4 web application – that runs just fine locally and on a “on premise” development web server.
- The site publishes out to Azure without error
- The "home" view (root) of the site shows a 403 error - forbidden.
- NO view on this site can be found - displays 404 errors.
- Looking at the published files using FileZilla – all the various files and views are there.

The only difference between this site, and a similar site that is also under development, and is publishing out to Azure webiste (and working) is that we added (or tried to add) Log4Net and Elmah to this problem child site.

We’ve pulled Log4Net back out, but (for now) have left Elmah in place.  That is the ONLY thing I can think of now that would be causing issues here.  Yet, I see blog posts of people that are using Elmah just fine with Azure Websites.

Any suggestions here on what might be going on with this site on Azure?

Comment: Removed Elmah completely. Updated a few references (via NuGet).  No joy. Same issue as noted above.  Created a fresh MVC 4 web application, and published to the same Azure website - works great! Something is really jacked with this code.

Comment: Turns out that one of my developers had put a block of code into the Global.asax.cs file... which hid the detailed error messages.
Removing this, I could see the REAL error message... which was a database related error.  The transformed web.config file (alters the connection string to point to SQL Azure versus local database) was not correctly done.  After correcting the connection string transformation, all is well!  Thank the Lord (and, thank detailed - valid - error messages ;-)

Comment: Can you please add the changes that you made in your global.asax.cs file as an answer?